# Why is Netlogo saying nothing named < link breed> has been defined?

Tags: netlogo

I'm running the following Netlogo code:

```
    directed-link-breed [buyer-loyal-links buyer-loyal-link]

to setup
  ca
  create-turtles 10 [
   set shape "person"
   set color green
   move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = black ]]
end

to buy
  ask turtles [create-buyer-loyal-link-to one-of other turtles ]
  ask turtles[
    ask my-buyer-loyal-links [set color blue]
  ]
end
```

and getting the message: Nothing named my-buyer-loyal-links has been defined.

Replacing 'my-buyer-loyal-links' with 'my-links' works fine. I thought to use a defined breed of link you replaced the word 'link' or 'links' with your own definition:

```
my-<breeds>
my-links
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: 'ask my-out-buyer-loyal-links [set color blue]' works fine, but I thought my-links ignores link direction and outputs all links?

Comment: It's a directed link breed, so you have to specify `in` or `out`.